# 500 Error Running Visual Studio ASP.NET Unit Test

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

I have the following method in my unit test project:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [HostType("ASP.NET")]
    [UrlToTest("http://localhost:3418/Web/SysCoord/ChooseEPA.aspx")]
    [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("%PathToWebRoot%")]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Page page = TestContext.RequestedPage;
        Assert.IsTrue(false, "Test ran, at least.");
    }
```

I'm getting this exception:

The test adapter 'WebHostAdapter' threw an exception while running test 'TestMethod1'. The web site could not be configured correctly; getting ASP.NET process information failed. Requesting 'http://localhost:3418/SysCoord/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd' returned an error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

The page works as it should in a browser at the url: http://localhost:3418/Web/SysCoord/ChooseEPA.aspx.

This physical path is: C:\ESI\HR_Connect2\BenefitChangeSystem\Application_DEV\Web\SysCoord.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**Update 1**

Added the following to my web.config file per this article.  Also made the web.config writable and killed/restarted the development web server.  No change in behavior.

```
<location path="VSEnterpriseHelper.axd">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

**Update 2**

Changing the AspNetDevelopmentServerHost attribute to the equivalent of [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("%PathToWebRoot%\solutionfolder\webfolder", "/webfolder")] resolved the 404 problem.

Unfortunately the test began to return a 500 error instead.  Progress, but not much.  Trial and error with a clean project led to the conclusion that references to custom classes in the  of the web.config were causing the problem.

For example:

```
    <profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyProfileProvider">
        <providers>
            <add name="MyProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ProfileConnectionString" applicationName="/MyApp" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"/>
        </providers>
        <properties>
            <add name="Theme" type="String" defaultValue="Default"/>
            <add name="LastLogon" type="DateTime"/>
            <add name="LastLogonIp" type="String"/>
            <!--
            <add name="EmployeeSearchCriteria" type="MyApplicationFramework.Profile.EmployeeSearchCriteria"/>
            <add name="DocumentSearchCriteria" type="MyApplicationFramework.Profile.DocumentSearchCriteria"/>
            -->
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

With the criteria types above commented out the test ran fine.  With them uncommented, the 500 error was returned.

Anyone had a similar problem in the past?

Answer (score 15):

I've had this problem before and at that point gave up after reading all I could google about it (including this thread).

The solution turned out to be simple in my case. All I had to do was not use ASP.NET test attributes and simply test the MVC project as a DLL.

#### Step 1

Remove the extra attributes from the test.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Page page = TestContext.RequestedPage;
    Assert.IsTrue(false, "Test ran, at least.");
}
```

#### Step 2

In Code Coverage, uncheck the MVC Project and add the MVC Project's DLL manually.

[image]

Voila, it get instrumented as a normal assembly, no errors, doesn't spin up the Development Server, also doesn't fail the Team Build.

Comment: Resharper didn't cause these problems. It would start a session for you with NUnit and take care of everything. This should really be in VS.

Answer (score 8):

I found that using vs2010 I am not restricted to just 4.0 applications. I DID however find that if testing a web application and you are using the old System.Web.Extensions version redirect you may get an error. Removing the following section from the **Web.config** file fixed my issue:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" appliesTo="v2.0.50727">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Good luck.

Comment: This fixed things for me after the upgrade from VS2008 to VS2010 had broken my tests, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same problem as you, however my experience was a little different.

I am on vista x64, my developers are in xp x64...they haven't been having any issues at all.  I just upgraded and could not run any unit test for a asp.net MVC project.  I was receiving the same 500 error you were receiving.

I turned off code coverage, everything magically started working.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your evidence I would guess that a reference to whichever assembly contains `MyApplicationFramework.Profile.EmployeeSearchCriteria` is missing from either the unit test project or the web project - though I would really think that you would only require the reference in the web project but I'm not knowledgeable about how the VS web server behaves when used as part of a unit test.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue testing a webservice where the project is .NET 3.51.  I was getting a IIS 500 error. 
 I removed the old assembly bindinds as commented by Hal Diggs and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message while unit testing a web app with Visual Studio 2010.  The only difference is that i was using IIS, ie i ommited the  `[AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("%PathToWebRoot%")]` directive.

I suspect the problem lies in the fact that i was using IIS version 5.1. More here:

http://ibsta.blogspot.com/2011/01/unit-testing-fun-under-visual-studio.html

Answer (score 1):

I setup a default unit test which popped up with the error, that brought me here. I just removed the following (below). Then clicked debug current context and boom, fine :S.

```
    [HostType("ASP.NET")]
    [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("C:\\Inetpub\\....]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem with unit testing.
And found the problem reason and also solve it.
The problem is only with access rights for the directory.

In my case I have installed VSTS on the different drive(d) then default.
So only to give the full access rights to the user **PCNAME\ASPNET** for whole directory **\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0**.

I m using the windows XP but if u are using window server then give access rights to the user **NetworkServices**.

By this solution i have solved my problem.
Hope u find something useful from this Answer.

Thanks,
Priyesh Patel

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the whole bit of web.config like this

```
<!-- <location path="VSEnterpriseHelper.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>   </location>   -->
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your web application is targeted to Framework 4.0.  If you are trying to test a
2.0, 3.0 or 3.5 project, you will get the (500) Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. Then I checked the properties of both the web project and the unit test project. And found that target framework was set different from each other. I set the target framework of both the project to .Net framework 4 (in my case). Finally ran the test method again and it worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was Resharper that caused this problem. Once I suspended it (Tools -> Options -> Resharper -> General -> Suspend) everything worked.
(using VS2010SP1 and Resharper Ultimate 2016.1.2)