# VS 2010 in ASP.NET Website, VSEnterpriseHelper.axd error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I have an ASP.NET website (.NET 4). I am trying to add Unit Testing (using Unit Testing Framework of VS 2010 ultimate) to code are located in the App_Code folder.

I have the following method in my unit test project:

```
[TestMethod()]
[HostType("ASP.NET")]
[AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("C:\\..\\MyProject", "/MyProject")]
[UrlToTest("http://localhost:45156/MyProject/Inicio.aspx")]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Page page = TestContext.RequestedPage;
    Assert.IsTrue(false, "Test ran, at least.");
}
```

I have the following web.config in my ASP.NET website:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <xhtmlConformance mode="Strict"/>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
            <!--another tags like pages, httpRuntime, compilation, sessionState, trace and globalization-->
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I'm getting this exception:

> "The test adapter 'WebHostAdpater' threw an exception while running
>   test 'TestMethod1'. The web site could not be configured correctly;
>   getting ASP.NET process information failed. Requesting
>   'http://127.0.0.1:45156/MyProject/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd'
>   (required) returned an error: The remote server returned an error:
>   (500) Internal Server Error..."

The page works as it should in a browser at the url: http://localhost:45156/MyProject/Inicio.aspx

This is very similar to the problem found here: 
 - [500 Error Running Visual Studio ASP.NET Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260432/500-error-running-visual-studio-asp-net-unit-test)
 - [Visual Studio 2010 Professional - Problem Unit-Testing Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017121/visual-studio-2010-professional-problem-unit-testing-web-services)
 - [ASP.NET Performance Profiling 404/500 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039152/asp-net-performance-profiling-404-500-errors)
 - [VS2010 and ASP.NET unit test problems / WebHostAdapter exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713926/vs2010-and-asp-net-unit-test-problems-webhostadapter-exception)
 - [Unit Testing ASP.net Web Site Project code stored in App_Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198555/unit-testing-asp-net-web-site-project-code-stored-in-app-code)

However, I haven't been found the solution for my project using the solutions than the similar problem. I have spent a couple days having this error. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had got a solution for this problem from [VS forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/81ea06d0-37d3-42d7-a618-66bd43841aa3/vs-2010-in-aspnet-website-vsenterprisehelperaxd-error?forum=vstest)